# wordpress - functions.php - preg_replace - <div<-tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

i have a problem with the posts of wordpress. Using the code embed function of an external blog publishing automatically on wordpress, the html code messes up my styling.

I do have the following code:

```
    <div class="entry-content">
     <div style="width:450px;margin:0 auto">
      <div style="position:relative;">
       <a target="_blank" href="DIFFERENT VARIABLES">
        <img width="???" alt="DIFFERENT VARIABLES" src="DIFFERENT VARIABLES" title="DIFFERENT VARIABLES" height="???" />
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
     <p><br/>
     <div style="text-align:center"><small>SEVERAL <a>-TAGS</small></div>
    </div>
```

The goal is to get rid of the second `<div>` with the style attributes and to get rid of the `<p><br/>`.

The best way would be a function for the function.php cause I do have lo of posts.

Can anyone help me please? I'm good enough to do some html coding, but this is far beyond my skills.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_function($content) {
    $div = '<div style="width:450px;margin:0 auto">';
    // Make sure the offending div is there.
    if (strpos($content, $div) !== false) {
         // Remove div.
         $content = str_replace($div, '', $content);
         // Remove one ending div tag.
         $content = str_replace('</div>', '', $content, 1);
         // Remove the p, br.
         $content = str_replace('<p><br/>', '', $content, 1);
    }
    return $content
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_function');
```

Add this to your functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a jQuery command to remove it, such as `jQuery('.entry-content br').remove()` ?

At the php level, you could use `the_content` filter to change the contents.

Comment: Definitely don't use javascript for this.